# Exponential Decay Function over a given range

Tags: exponential-function

I try to exponentially decrease a value (force) over specific 10 to 11 range.

In other words, if a length of a vector **d** is 10 cm then **force** needs to be 1000 Newton.
If length **d** is close to 11 cm then **force** should be close to 0.

My exponential decreasing formula is doing it, but on a large scale, and i have no idea how to bring it within 10-11 range.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is a demo in excel with the formula unrolled:

Cell M16 = 1000

Cell L17 = 10.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the exponential function:
$$f(d)=Ae^{rd},$$
where $r$ is the rate of decay and $A$ is a parameter.

Now plug the two points: $(d,f)=(10,1000)$ and $(11,0)$ to make up a system of equations for $d$ and $A$. Once you find the function, you can use it in Excel.

Comment: thanks i am afraid its over my head to solve it sadly, hence the question